# How to compare dict with timestamps

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, compare

So im trying to make a dictionary that will have each *product* you monitor in there, when something restocks it will check that dictionary and see if the item is in there, if it’s not it will add it. Once it’s added it will put in each size that restocked and a time stamp per size. Next run, if something restocks it will takes these sizes and check if they are in the dictionary, if they are it will compare the current timestamp with the ones inside the dictionary. Basically putting a cooldown per size.

What I have done so far is a demo of it:

```
import random
import sys
import time
import re
from datetime import timedelta, datetime


def randomNumber():
    payload = {
        "sizes": {}
    }
    numbers = {}
    for x in range(10):
        numbers.update({f'US {random.randint(1, 10)}': datetime.now()})

    payload['sizes'] = numbers

    return payload


def demo():
    firstList = randomNumber()

    while True:
        secondList = randomNumber()

        if len(secondList['sizes']) > len(firstList['sizes']):  # Not sure if this is needed but couldn't get another other ideas here to compare

            restockSizes = []
            restocked = False
            for key, value in secondList['sizes'].items():
                if key in firstList['sizes'].keys():
                    timenow = datetime.now()
                    elapsed = timenow - value

                    if elapsed > timedelta(seconds=5):
                        restockSizes.append(f'{key}')
                        restocked = True
                    else:
                        restockSizes.append(f'{key}')
                        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

            if restocked:
                print(f'Restocked: {restockSizes}')
                firstList = secondList

        else:
            print("No restock.")
            firstList = secondList

demo()
```

There is some concern that I am not sure if its actually working as I described. As for now there is some stuff that I feel i'm unclear about which is if there is any reason for me to `firstList = secondList` in the `else statement`

Also im not sure if if `len(secondList['sizes']) > len(firstList['sizes']):` is also needed in my case if I do have to compare between firstList and secondList?

Hopefully someone can see the flaws and help me out!

**Lets say our delta is minute=5**

First request:

**US 3: 22:23, US 4: 22:23, US 5 22:23**

Second request (1min after first req):

US 3: 22:23, US 4: 22:23, US 5 22:23, **US 6: 22:24, US 8: 22:24**

Third request (5 min after first req):

**US 3: 22:28, US 4: 22:28, US 5 22:28**, US 6: 22:24, US 8: 22:24

Fourth request (6min after first req):

US 3: 22:28, US 4: 22:28, US 5 22:28, **US 6: 22:29, US 8: 22:29**

Comment: I'm having a very hard time following your description of what this code is supposed to be doing.  What does it mean to "restock" if you aren't tracking the quantities of different items?  It looks like you add the size to the "restocked" list regardless of the cooldown so I don't understand what the list represents.  Maybe you could come up with an example that describes how this is supposed to be working?

Comment: @SamStafford Right im on it, Would any outprint of what im trying to get for result be a sort of help?

Comment: Yes, that'd be very helpful!

Comment: @SamStafford Something like that maybe? Would that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand whether the point of the code is to generate requests such that nothing is requested which has been requested more recently than five minutes, or whether it's supposed to accept arbitrary requests and do something based on the difference (what?)...

Comment: What does the bolded part of the output represent?  Is the input the entire request, and the return value just the bolded part (i.e. the parts with more than a 5 minute difference)?

Comment: So basically there is some sites that are having bad cache (Which wont help if you clear the cache and so on) and they have a bug where you refresh the site and see in the product US 5 and US 6, then you refresh again and its empty (nothing in stock) and then if you refresh like 5 times then you will se the US 5 and US 6 again, sort of a cache issue but what im trying here is to minimize the spam and thats why I want to make a sort of cooldown to see, if the US 5 and US 6 is in the first request dict and they have a time, then we check with delta if the time has passed over 5 min.

Comment: @SamStafford and if it has then it means a restock basically. So then we want to print out (These sizes has restocked and there is for example US 7 and US 8 aswell in the site that are avaliable) then we print all sizes that we managed to get through scrape. If that makes a sense?

Comment: So am I understanding correctly that you have a stream of batched requests coming in (for a certain set of sizes), and as requests come in you want to filter out sizes that have been touched by some previous request in the last five minutes?

Comment: @SamStafford Exactly, I wish I could explain the same way as you just wrote but yes. I would like to filter the "new" sizes and the sizes that has been over timedelta(minutes=5).

Comment: @SamStafford In my case the `secondList = randomNumber()` will be the one that is always requesting and `firstList` is something we have to "compare" with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this demonstrates the general idea of what you're looking for:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random
from typing import Dict, List


class RequestFilter:
    """Tracks requests and filters them to prevent hammering."""

    def __init__(self, cooldown: timedelta):
        self._cooldown = cooldown
        self._requests: Dict[str, datetime] = {}

    def filter(self, requests: List[str], time: datetime) -> List[str]:
        """Filter requests to only those that haven't been made
        previously within our defined cooldown period."""
        # Get filtered set of requests.
        filtered = [
            r for r in list(set(requests))
            if (
                r not in self._requests
                or time - self._requests[r] >= self._cooldown
            )
        ]
        # Refresh timestamps for requests we're actually making.
        for r in filtered:
            self._requests[r] = time
        return filtered


if __name__ == '__main__':
    time = datetime.now()
    request_filter = RequestFilter(timedelta(minutes=5))
    for _ in range(100):
        requests = [
            f"US {random.randint(1, 10)}"
            for _ in range(5)
        ]
        print(request_filter.filter(requests, time), time)
        time += timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Note that I made the filtering function take a timestamp instead of actually using `datetime.now()` internally -- that way you can unit-test it with fake timestamps instead of having to patch out `datetime`, or making it actually sleep for a minute in between fake requests.  :)

In real life you'd just say `request_filter.filter(requests, datetime.now())` to make it use the real time.  Or you could use this as your `__main__` function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from time import sleep
    request_filter = RequestFilter(timedelta(minutes=5))
    for _ in range(100):
        requests = [
            f"US {random.randint(1, 10)}"
            for _ in range(5)
        ]
        print(request_filter.filter(requests, datetime.now()), datetime.now())
        sleep(60)
```

Comment: Oh lord, There is so many thoughts here but I will try to see if I can understand. Is there a possibility to see make it loop forever and also not this fast, it seems to do the 100 really fast so I can't really try out the functions I would say. My real life would be something like | Call first request to have something to compare with -> Make a while loop that requests second request -> and we compare this all the time til forever basically. If you know what I mean?

Comment: Because when testing this, if I understood correctly. if we do 100 request as you did, most likely we would get all sizes already by lets say 20 requests. in that case it should say that "No restock" since we dont have any new sizes nor none of them have reached over 5 minutes either. If you know what I mean?

Comment: Please spend some time trying the code and read my explanation of why it doesn't matter that it goes "really fast".  :)  Look carefully at the output -- see how by the time it's done you're almost two hours in the future?

Comment: I added an edit with code that makes it work in real time.  The output is exactly the same (+/- randomness), you'll just have to wait a lot longer because it's using real delays instead of simulated delays.

Comment: Ohhhh now I see, Holy **** this is actually amazing. I would need to spend more time on learning this code for sure but im pretty sure it will be something i'm looking for. Im starting to understand it more and more. I tried to change sleep to (1,3 sec random) and also changed timedelta to 1 min. than it is easier to actually see it. You are amazing. so in my case the `request` is the one that is my `firstLine['sizes']` right, if I understood correctly

Comment: Exactly right; you can use any arbitrary list of strings as the "requests", so they could be sizes, or they could be strings like "PRODUCT NAME - SIZE", or sets of URL params, or whatever.

Comment: I wish that I could kiss you honestly. This is actually super amazing and I do need to investigate it alot more but oh my dear! You have made my month, year or everything! however im not quite sure what you meant with `for _ in range(5)` inside the requests but I can look at that later on but oh my. This is pure amazing

Comment: `for _ in range(5)` just means "do this five times"`.

Comment: Just a quicky question before sleep. I guess it would be optimal to do something like in the __main__

instead of `print(request_filter.filter(requests, datetime.now()), datetime.now())` to do maybe `if request_filter.filter(requests, datetime.now())) print(the new size) else print("no restock")` ?

Comment: Depends entirely on what you want to use it for!  I'm assuming that in a "real world" application you're not printing this output to the console, you're handing the filtered list of requests off to some other module, and it results in a no-op if the list is empty.

Comment: Well thats true, I would actually print out what size that got restocked but I wouldn't print out "no restock" because that would probably be too spammy for console. The only thing I would do here is actually call `secondList = randomNumber()` over and over until there is a restock and then print out what size :) But I guess then I would just need to apply that into the `        requests = [
            f"US {random.randint(1, 10)}"
            for _ in range(5)
        ]` in here.

Comment: I mean I don't want to ask too much, I would rather just study this code and see if I can apply it to the way I want but I guess it has been made lots already! Im kinda just chocked that it was so simple for you compare to what I tried to do

Comment: Hello mate! Hope you had a wonderful days every since we last spoke! I realized I have a problem once again which I haven't realized until now. The problem is that if I change minutes delay to seconds etc 1 sec. It will ping all sizes over and over again since we have that low delay. What I want to do is somehow see if there has been a restock and what I mean etc is that. If we have in our list [US 9] for over 1 hour with 1 second delay. it will ping 60 times obviously. But what I want to do is that if I request a site 100 times and it pings everytime US 9...

Comment: without any restock or size disappears then we skip and wait until the size has disappeared or size decrease. A solution would be maybe see the length of the sizes available when doing the actual request to see if it has decreased or increased and THEN use your function to see if the size has been restocked or not. But im not sure if there is any better solution than checking by the length?